# What is the equivalent of telnet localhost 25 with ssh?

Tags: ssh, smtp, telnet

What is the equivalent of

```
telnet localhost 25
```

using SSH ?

Clarification : I would like to have an SMTP connection with a server using SSH, just like it can be done with a command like `telnet localhost 25`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  A "secure mail connection"?  Connect to an ssh-daemon via telnet?  Your question is more than ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking "What is the way to connect to an SMTP server using SSH instead of telnet?" the answer is there is none.

SSH only communicates over ports using the SSH protocol. Using it to connect to any other port will fail, because SSH will try to speak the SSH protocol, which will not be understood by an SMTP server (or FTP, or other server processes).

You can connect to other SSH servers which run on other ports, but I interpreted your question to mean you wanted to talk SMTP to a mail server.

Comment: Huh? You can specify an arbitrary ssh port.

Comment: Correct.  I'll edit my answer to clarify that using it to connect to non-SSH processes on other ports will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Telnet is a raw TCP client - so surely the Linux equivalent is `nc localhost 25`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to connect to localhost using the default port, do

```
ssh localhost
```

If you want to specifically connect to port 25 do:

```
ssh -p 25 localhost
```

Comment: `-P` should be lowercase I think. Anyway, `telnet localhost 25` and `ssh -p 25 localhost` do not produce the same output. When I use the ssh command there is no output; I have just a blank line and I have to do CTRL+C to quit. Is it normal?

Comment: @Gradient you're quite right, it is upper case for `scp`, I always confuse that.

Comment: And now, what happens when you're connected to port 25 on localhost (or any other host)?

Comment: @ott-- you can test your ssh setup? Search me, ask the OP.

Comment: The smtp servers reply with `ssh_exchange_identification: 500 unrecognized command` resp. `502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized`.

Answer (score 1):

Telnet equivalent are rlogin, rexec and rsh

a secure alternative is SSH